# Convert Code from .NetFramework 3.5 to Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, uwp, portable-class-library

I have the following code working fine in a project, I can reference it in Android but not in UWP. This is why I want to convert the code into my PCL project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace NetScraperLibrary
{
public class NetScraper
{
    public NetScraper()
    {
    }

    public ScrapedPage GetPage(string uri)
    {
        string strWebPage = "";
        // create request
        System.Net.WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        // get response
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse objResponse;
        objResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        // get correct charset and encoding from the server's header
        string Charset = objResponse.CharacterSet;
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Charset);

        // read response into memory stream
        MemoryStream memoryStream;
        using (Stream responseStream = objResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int byteCount;
            do
            {
                byteCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
            } while (byteCount > 0);
        }

        // set stream position to beginning
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream, encoding);
        strWebPage = sr.ReadToEnd();

        // Check real charset meta-tag in HTML
        int CharsetStart = strWebPage.IndexOf("charset=");
        if (CharsetStart > 0)
        {
            CharsetStart += 8;
            int CharsetEnd = strWebPage.IndexOfAny(new[] { ' ', '\"', ';' }, CharsetStart);
            string RealCharset =
                   strWebPage.Substring(CharsetStart, CharsetEnd - CharsetStart);

            // real charset meta-tag in HTML differs from supplied server header???
            if (RealCharset != Charset)
            {
                // get correct encoding
                Encoding CorrectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(RealCharset);

                // reset stream position to beginning
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // reread response stream with the correct encoding
                StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(memoryStream, CorrectEncoding);

                strWebPage = sr2.ReadToEnd();
                // Close and clean up the StreamReader
                sr2.Close();
            }
        }

        // dispose the first stream reader object
        sr.Close();

        ScrapedPage page = new ScrapedPage(uri, strWebPage);//sb.ToString());
        return page;
    }

}
}
```

The major issue, is that `objResponse.CharacterSet` does not exist, very weird?
Also the closing of streams `sr2.Close(); sr.Close();`. finally webresponse cannot be called synchronously anymore. Can anybody help with these missing functionalities for the conversion, since I have not been able to figure it out?

Comment: Xamarin is moving to .NET Standard 2.0 support. You are supposed to drop PCL and move to that new platform too.

Comment: @LexLi it seemed like .NET standard 2.0 is not really ready or am I missing some info?

Comment: @JTIM if you wait a few weeks, it'll be ready :-)

Comment: @karann-MSFT I feel this teaser should have some more information? [very excited!]

Comment: @karann-MSFT any update? Or answer to the question?

Comment: @JTIM check this out https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24